# Availability of method vars within a sub-function

Tags: php, class, methods, scope

Referencing a method parameter variable from within a sub-function of that method doesn't seem to work even when *global* is specified.

```
public function sortArray(&$array, $keyToCompare){// BOOL sortArray( ARR &$array, STR $keyToCompare )
    function cmpVals($pairA, $pairB){
        global $keyToCompare;
        return strcmp($pairA[$keyToCompare], $pairB[$keyToCompare]);
    }
    return uasort($array, 'cmpVals');
}
```

Is it even possible to reference a method parameter from within a sub-function? If so... how?

For my specific example above I realise I could use a closure to achieve the same goal but I don't want the script to be PHP 5.3 dependent.

Comment: PHP Doesn't support scoping like that.  It's as simple as that...

Comment: Why do you need to nest function?

Comment: It doesn't? argh! How can I do this then?
I just need to define the nested function so that it can be used with the uasort function

Comment: I'd highly recommend to read [php.net](http://www.php.net/archive/2010.php#id2010-12-16-1) news: php 5.2 support is ending, so you should start migrating to v5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you can't make it static?

```
class YourClassName {
    public static $keyToCompare;
    public function sortArray(&$array, $keyToCompare){// BOOL sortArray( ARR &$array, STR $keyToCompare )
        self::$keyToCompare = $keyToCompare;
        function cmpVals($pairA, $pairB){
            $keyToCompare = YourClassName::$keyToCompare;
            return strcmp($pairA[$keyToCompare], $pairB[$keyToCompare]);
        }
        return uasort($array, 'cmpVals');
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I hadn't thought of it? Many thanks, it's not the most elegant but it works damn well (a little like me)

Comment: My original response did mention it was hacky :)

Answer (score 1):

You seemed to be already using OOP in PHP 5.3. Might as well create a sorter class?

```
class Sorter{

    private $key;

    function __construct($key){
        $this->key = $key;
    }

    private function compare($a, $b){
        return strcmp($a[$this->key], $b[$this->key]);
    }

    public function sort($a){
        uasort($a, array($this, 'compare'));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is an anonymous function:

```
public function sortArray(&$array, $keyToCompare){
    return uasort($array, function($pairA, $pairB) uses ($keyToCompare) {
        return strcmp($pairA[$keyToCompare], $pairB[$keyToCompare]);
    });
}
```

Untested, on a train :D, but see [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) for more info.

FYI, the pass by reference is unnecessary since you don't modify the array.. PHP won't make a copy so there is no memory issues passing by value.

Comment: I'm on PHP 5.2.17 and anonymous funcs don't seem to work; that'd be much more beautiful though. Have fun on the train.